# Why i get negative destination address from the packet

Tags: java, tcp, ip, packet

I'm trying to parse the packet to get destination IP address and convert it to hostname. The problem is that i'm getting a negative destination address, like this:

- IP Version:4
- Header Length:20
- Total Length:60
- Protocol:6
- Source IP:10.0.2.0
- Destination IP:-83.-4.102.16
- Unknown host

---

- IP Version:4
- Header Length:20
- Total Length:92
- Protocol:6
- Source IP:-64.-88.1.5
- Destination IP:54.-9.-67.-15

---

```
int buffer = packet.get();
    int version;
    int headerlength;
    version = buffer >> 4;
    headerlength = buffer & 0x0F;
    headerlength *= 4;
    Log.d(TAG, "IP Version:"+version);
    Log.d(TAG, "Header Length:"+headerlength);

    String status = "";
    status += "Header Length:"+headerlength;

    buffer = packet.get();      //DSCP + EN
    buffer = packet.getChar();  //Total Length

    Log.d(TAG, "Total Length:"+buffer);

    buffer = packet.getChar();  //Identification
    buffer = packet.getChar();  //Flags + Fragment Offset
    buffer = packet.get();      //Time to Live
    buffer = packet.get();      //Protocol

    Log.d(TAG, "Protocol:"+buffer);

    status += "  Protocol:"+buffer;

    buffer = packet.getChar();  //Header checksum

    String sourceIP  = "";
    buffer = packet.get();  //Source IP 1st Octet
    sourceIP += buffer;
    sourceIP += ".";

    buffer = packet.get();  //Source IP 2nd Octet
    sourceIP += buffer;
    sourceIP += ".";

    buffer = packet.get();  //Source IP 3rd Octet
    sourceIP += buffer;
    sourceIP += ".";

    buffer = packet.get();  //Source IP 4th Octet
    sourceIP += buffer;

    Log.d(TAG, "Source IP:"+sourceIP);

    status += "   Source IP:"+sourceIP;

    String destIP  = "";
    buffer = packet.get();  //Destination IP 1st Octet
    destIP += buffer;
    destIP += ".";

    buffer = packet.get();  //Destination IP 2nd Octet
    destIP += buffer;
    destIP += ".";

    buffer = packet.get();  //Destination IP 3rd Octet
    destIP += buffer;
    destIP += ".";

    buffer = packet.get();  //Destination IP 4th Octet
    destIP += buffer;

    Log.d(TAG, "Destination IP:" + destIP);

    status += "   Destination IP:"+destIP;

    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(destIP);
        String host = addr.getHostName();
        Log.d(TAG, "Hostname:" + host);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Unknown host");
    }
```

Am i doing something wrong? And how should i do it right?

Comment: What's the return type of `packet.get()`?

Comment: It is used to get byte of the current position of the bytebuffer and increases their position by 1. Link -> [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`packet.get()` returns `byte`. In java `byte` is signed, you expect a unsigned value however. Using `byte` you get negative values for any byte, that should be greater than `127`

#### Example

```
byte b = 0xFF; // 255
System.out.println(b == -1); // prints true
```

---

To "convert" the `byte` to the correct unsigned value, you have to use a primitive integral type that uses more than 1 byte and do a little trick to get the unsigned value:

```
byte b = // your value goes here
int printInt = ((int) b) & 0xFF;
// printInt contains the unsigned value of the byte.
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped. Really appreciate that man! :) P.S Do i need to make this thread "Solved" or something?